# How do I retrieve body of client request in a spring webflux unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, spring-webflux

I have a `@Service` which uses a `WebClient` to return a `Mono<Something>`. I want to test that the service adds the right data to the request - headers, URI, body. My test's approach is to inject a mocked `WebClient.Builder` into the service, and provide a `WebClient` with a custom exchange function:

```
@BeforeEach
void preProgramWebClientBuilder() {
    webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl(TEST_REMOTE_BASE_URL)
        .exchangeFunction(clientRequest -> {
             // ...
        }).build();
    // webClientBuilder is the mockito-managed mock
    when(webClientBuilder.baseUrl(anyString())).thenReturn(webClientBuilder);
    when(webClientBuilder.build()).thenReturn(webClient);
}
```

This works well, for checking request host/path/query parameters/headers, with the exchange function either performing the checks itself, or setting the `clientRequest` aside for the test to do the checks. But I have not found a way to extract the body from the `clientRequest` object, to perform assertions on it.

Fully mocking the WebClient yields some ugly test initialization code, which I'd like to avoid. Is there a decent way to extract the request body from the `clientRequest`?

Just to mention it: I don't see how I can use a `StepVerifier` here. `StepVerifier` expects to get the `Publisher` to verify - and getting the body of the request as a publisher is exactly what I haven't managed to do. A `WebTestClient` has the same problem - I can perform a request with it, then do assertions on the response, but I can't substitute it for the regular `WebClient` in the service in order to perform assertions on the request emitted by the service.

Comment: Instead of mocking WebClient you might have a more meaningful test if you use WireMock to mock the remote service: http://wiremock.org/

Comment: That would transform my unit test into a component test - a test that no longer tests a single component in isolation. That's not what I'm after.

Comment: That could certainly be another discussion but personally I don't see too much value in this sort of unit test exactly because of this mocking mess it requires.

Comment: Basically, to run a similar amount of tests, I'd need hundreds of times more time. Like several minutes instead of a few seconds, when you have many tests. IMO, not being able to capture the body of the request is a shortfall of the framework, from a testability point of view. Which is why I'd expect this to actually be possible, just me not to know how to do it.